# json взять объекты из массива jquery

Tags: jquery, json

В *jquery* полный ноль, прошу прощения за возможно нелепый вопрос.

Есть такой json:

```
   {    "success": true,
        "data": {
            "fructs": [{
                "a": 53.8977737,
                "b": 27.5517273,
                "angle": 0,
                "mark": "Яблоко",
                "color": "Красный",
                "bbbb": 0,
                "zree": 40,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": 1
            },
            {
                "a": 52.9775352,
                "b": 36.102005,
                "angle": 220,
                "test": "ccc",
                "mark": "Вишня",
                "color": "",
                "bbbb": 0,
                "zree": 60,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": 1
            },
            {
                "a": 55.7416407,
                "b": 37.5990335,
                "angle": 0,
                "test": "рфффф",
                "mark": "Вишня",
                "color": "Черный",
                "bbbb": 0,
                "zree": 50,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": null
            },
            {
                "a": 55.7537043,
                "b": 37.6306607,
                "angle": 0,
                "test": "фывыфвфывфы",
                "mark": "Горох",
                "color": "Белый",
                "bbbb": 0,
                "zree": 60,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": null
            },
            {
                "a": 55.7456493,
                "b": 37.6358455,
                "angle": 0,
                "test": "фывфывф",
                "mark": "Арбуз",
                "color": "Красный",
                "bbbb": 0,
                "zree": 50,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": null
            },
            {
                "a": 55.7794533,
                "b": 37.6291466,
                "angle": 187,
                "test": "x50",
                "mark": "Яблоко",
                "bbbbDistance": 475,
                "color": "черный",
                "bbbb": 38,
                "zree": 40,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": 1
            },
            {
                "a": 55.7324982,
                "b": 37.6640549,
                "angle": 108,
                "test": "x50",
                "mark": "Яблоко",
                "bbbbDistance": 537.5,
                "color": "белый",
                "bbbb": 43,
                "zree": 40,
                "discount": 0,
                "multiplier": null
            }]
        }
    }
```

Делаю так:

```
  $.getJSON('fructs.json', function(data) { 
            $.each(data.fructs, function(a,b) {
                $.each(a, function(index, obj) {
                    console.log(a,b)
                    });
                });

            });
```

Мне нужно взять только значения **a, b** из каждого элемента массива

Получаю ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Как взять нужные значения?

Лог:

```
jquery-latest.js:357 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.each (jquery-latest.js:357)
    at Object.success (map.html:28)
    at fire (jquery-latest.js:3119)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.js:3231)
    at done (jquery-latest.js:9275)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-latest.js:9685)
```

Comment: Можно узнать какой лог вам дал этот объект который вы дали в вопросе?

Comment: @StackOverflow добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот ваша ошибка, вы делаете `$.each(a, function(index, obj)` но ведь там `a` это просто индекс, а не вложенный объект.

Вот пример кода с вашими данными.

```js
var data = { "success": true,
              "data": {
                "fructs": [{
                  "a": 53.8977737,
                  "b": 27.5517273,
                  "angle": 0,
                  "mark": "Яблоко",
                  "color": "Красный",
                  "bbbb": 0,
                  "zree": 40,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": 1
                },
                {
                  "a": 52.9775352,
                  "b": 36.102005,
                  "angle": 220,
                  "test": "ccc",
                  "mark": "Вишня",
                  "color": "",
                  "bbbb": 0,
                  "zree": 60,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": 1
                },
                {
                  "a": 55.7416407,
                  "b": 37.5990335,
                  "angle": 0,
                  "test": "рфффф",
                  "mark": "Вишня",
                  "color": "Черный",
                  "bbbb": 0,
                  "zree": 50,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": null
                },
                {
                  "a": 55.7537043,
                  "b": 37.6306607,
                  "angle": 0,
                  "test": "фывыфвфывфы",
                  "mark": "Горох",
                  "color": "Белый",
                  "bbbb": 0,
                  "zree": 60,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": null
                },
                {
                  "a": 55.7456493,
                  "b": 37.6358455,
                  "angle": 0,
                  "test": "фывфывф",
                  "mark": "Арбуз",
                  "color": "Красный",
                  "bbbb": 0,
                  "zree": 50,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": null
                },
                {
                  "a": 55.7794533,
                  "b": 37.6291466,
                  "angle": 187,
                  "test": "x50",
                  "mark": "Яблоко",
                  "bbbbDistance": 475,
                  "color": "черный",
                  "bbbb": 38,
                  "zree": 40,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": 1
                },
                {
                  "a": 55.7324982,
                  "b": 37.6640549,
                  "angle": 108,
                  "test": "x50",
                  "mark": "Яблоко",
                  "bbbbDistance": 537.5,
                  "color": "белый",
                  "bbbb": 43,
                  "zree": 40,
                  "discount": 0,
                  "multiplier": null
                }]
              }
            };
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each(data.data.fructs, function(a,b) {
    $.each(b, function(key, val) {
      if(key == 'a' || key == 'b'){
        console.log(key,val);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

А вот кусок кода который можете добавить вместо вашего такой:

```
$.getJSON('fructs.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.data.fructs, function(a,b) {
    $.each(b, function(key, val) {
      if(key == 'a' || key == 'b'){
        console.log(key,val);
      }
    });
  });
});
```